# Check SSL-Certificate expiration date without authorization

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

So far I'm able to get the expiration date of the SSL-certificate of web pages where I don't have to authorize with a username & password with:

```
class Program
{
  static void ReadExpirDate()
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();

    X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
    X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

    string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
    Console.WriteLine(cedate);
  }
}
```

But if I try to get the expiration date of a web page where I need to authorize with a username & password before I can access it, I get a System.Net.WebException "error:(401) Unauthorized" exception.
Is there any possible way to get the SSL certificate expiration date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Is actually making a call to the specified Url which is unauthorised, that's where the exception is being thrown, if you do this then you can use the `Certificate` Property from the returned `request` despite the `Exception`:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
X509Certificate cert2 = null;
HttpWebResponse response =null;

try {
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
    cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
} catch {
    X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
    cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
} finally {
    response.Close();
}

if (cert2 != null) {
    string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
    Console.WriteLine(cedate);
}
```

This code would be subject to some better Exception handling and refactoring, but it should work.

Comment: When I left out the response part I don't get the unauthorized exception yes. But now I got a exception in the line "X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);" because cert is null.

Comment: Ah my bad, I think in that case you should just get the certificate for the Host part of the URL instead of the full page URL? Unless you know that in your case this won't work?

Comment: Well I think the main problem is that the site I try to get the certificate from, doesn't load before you sign in. So I'll never get a full response from it. I guess I need to look for a opportunity to get the certificate without the response maybe. E.g. In my browser I'm able to look up the certificate manually without signing in onto the site.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what you mean with only getting the certificate from Host part of the URL?

Comment: var uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/somerestrictedresource.html");
requestUri = uri.Scheme + uri.Authority;
So then you'll be getting the certificate for "https://www.google.com" which you will be able to make a request to, if the entire host is authenticated (like a pure API server might be) then I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: I tried it, but the URL I try to access is already "only" the Host Part

Comment: Try catching the exception, and then executing the code as normal (e.g. do the request.ServicePoint.Certificate on it, I think the certificate data might still be in the response even though you got a 401.

Comment: I'll edit the answer with the right version, glad we got there :)

Comment: According to Microsoft this won't work for .net 5.0. Starting in .NET Core 1.0 and later including .NET 5.0 and later, the Certificate property always returns null. The ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is the recomendded way to access the server certificate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.certificate?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 7):

Use `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to get certificate before Authorization

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetOptionValue("url"));

request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
    (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate? certificate,
     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain? chain,
     System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
         string expirationDate = certificate.GetExpirationDateString();
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: Starting in .NET Core 1.0 and later including .NET 5.0 and later, the Certificate property always returns null. The ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is the recomendded way to access the server certificate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.certificate?view=net-5.0

Comment: Remember to call `request.GetResponse();` in order to send request and validate expirationDate

Answer (score 6):

HttpWebRequest is now obsolete. I ended up using this code:

```
// Create an HttpClientHandler object and set to use default credentials
using var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

// Set custom server validation callback
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (requestMessage, certificate, x509Chain, SslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    // It is possible inpect the certificate provided by server
    Console.WriteLine($"Requested URI: {requestMessage.RequestUri}");

    if (certificate is null)
        return false;

    Console.WriteLine($"Effective date: {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Exp date: {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {certificate.Subject}");

    return true;
};

// Create an HttpClient object
using var client = new HttpClient(handler);

using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/");

// wait for callback
await Task.Delay(10000);
```